# "Send email when ownership is assigned?" Due Date functionality

Tags: alert, tasks

I'm writing a blog article about the above feature (under lists' Advanced settings) and I'm finding it goshdarn hard to find a definitive reference on the subject.

In short, I've heard passing reference to this setting sending e-mails to a task/issue's owner when its due date is today, is this true? If so, is this a feature in all SharePoint versions?

If there's any MSDN documentation you know of on the subject I'd be very grateful for a link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Purpose

*Send e-mail when ownership is assigned* option corresponds to [EnableAssignToEmail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.enableassigntoemail.aspx) property in [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms434081.aspx) and according to MSDN:

> this value specify whether e-mail notification is enabled for the list

- Alerts are sent to recipient specified in *Assigned To* field
- There is no dependency to *Due Date* field

### Alert types

When *Send e-mail when ownership is assigned* option is enabled for List, alerts are sent based on the following criteria:

- task assigned
- task deleted
- task changed
- task changes ownership

### Supported types of lists

*Send e-mail when ownership is assigned* option is available only for the following [types of lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splisttemplatetype.aspx):

- Tasks
- GanttTasks
- Issue

Comment: So this means Microsoft is wrong? "When this option is enabled, the users who are specified in the Assigned to field receive an email message if a task is assigned to them, if a task changes ownership, if a task is overdue, and when a task is completed." http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2412093

Comment: To my knowledge (SharePoint 2010 env.),  notifications are not sent after the following changes 1)when a task is completed 2) if a task is overdue. Updated answer with additional change that was not mentioned - if a task changes ownership

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand, this option is only available in lists where the Assigned To Column is present within the content type.
 It is used to notify the person or group that the task has been assigned to them, rather than to notify the creator that someone has picked it up. When your create a new item in a list where this enabled the following message appears on the newForm

“The content of this item will be sent as an e-mail message to the person or group assigned to the item.”

As far as i know, the due date plays no part in it

This feature is present within all versions of SharePoint  2010, including foundation. And is Not present at all within SharePoint 2013 as far I am aware(I guess it wasn’t popular).

There is some infomation about it being used in SP2007 here

http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Lq_xG4z3cYwC&pg=PA188&lpg=PA188&dq#v=onepage&q&f=false

Edit: Some further reading in this blog post
http://sharepointalert.info/2010/07/email-when-ownership-is-assigned-item-level-permissions/

Answer (score 2):

If you have a task list as described above and want users to get an email when a task assigned to them is due today then a simple way to achieve this would be to have alerts on a view.

Create a view that is filtered:
Assigned to = [Me]
Due Date = [Today]

This view will only show items assigned to the logged in user and which are due today.

All you now need to do is get the users to create an alert on that view.  Note that you will not see the option to alert on a view until you have a filtered view in place.

Comment: While this solves the same requirement as the feature mentioned, it doesn't address the question. Perhaps it will be of use to other people, but not me unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry Stuart, perhaps I will learn to read the question properly.  I have not seen any documentation on that but as far as I am aware it only sends emails when they are assigned or when they change.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointcustomizationlegacy/thread/45478817-a541-4f61-9645-905f0f211b63/

Seems this is a common issue.

Comment: Unfortunately not. That MSDN question doesn't even mention the feature I asked about... I've edited my question to make it clear I'm asking about a built-in setting on lists.