# Send email using SharePoint Designer to the users in Person and group field

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, email

I would like to send email notification to one or more people that exist in a person or group field.

Is this possible using a workflow in SharePoint Designer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use `Send Email` activity. And choose the Person Or Group.

https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Send-e-mail-in-a-workflow-11d5f9dd-955f-412c-b70f-cde4214204f4

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple and easy to send an email from the SharePoint Designer.

You would be required to select the `Send Email` option from the `Action Menu` as shown below.

[image]

Once this option is selected a dialog box will be opened where you will be able to find options for the constructing the mail. Also in the To and CC fields you can select the members of the People and Group field.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the email you want to send is triggered by setting the `assigned to` field of a task  or issue listitem, you can enable a (task or issue) list's `Send e-mail when ownership is assigned` option.

"["Send email when ownership is assigned?" Due Date functionality](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/65056/send-email-when-ownership-is-assigned-due-date-functionality)