# How to a sharepoint list as alert receiver?

Tags: sharepoint-online, alert

I have a list of person with the same alert needs.
This alerts are listening document from differents locations.
I dont want to change all those alerts after every changes on this list of person.
Do you have a solution ?

(The best solutions whould be to set a sharepoint group as receivers in the alert configuration but it doesn't work).

Comment: I have not tried this, but workaround can be to use designer workflow to send mail to SharePoint group. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138529/send-email-using-sharepoint-designer-to-the-users-in-person-and-group-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the SharePoint Group has no email address, the alert email cannot send to the members of the SP group.

As an alternative, you can create a Mail-enabled security group in Office 365 Admin center: Groups tab->Groups->Add a group button.
[image]

Then in the set alert page, assign the “Send Alert to” this mail-enabled security group.

Comment: This is too tricky, my users have to do this. I tought it could just send email foreach person in the group...