# How to send email notification to a GROUP

Tags: sharepoint-online, alert, distribution-lists

My scenario:

I am using SharePoint online and i need to send an email each time a file is modified/created in a library. I have tried creating an alert but i can't send alerts to a group. I have tried using Microsoft Flow,but the same result.

Note: My group need to to have subgroup which can't be achieve using mail-enabled security group.

Solution tried:
1. add a mail-enabled security group to an Office 365 group
2. add an Office 365 security group to a SharePoint group
3. add a security group to a security group

The only solution that did work was create a mail-enabled security group but here the problem we can't add another group to a mail-enabled security group.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you checked if the Groups are SP groups or O365 Security groups?

Comment: @DvG I created security group. My aim is to add sub group to one Main group and send alert to that main group.

Comment: My question - Why do you need a mail-enabled security group as a sub-group. Why can't you use 2 separate mail-enabled-sec groups and put it into one SharePoint group?... Though it's your choice so I am keeping it on you.   Additionally, in O365 - SPOL there is a concept of Distribution Lists where you can add as many groups/sec-groups/mail-enabled-sec-groups/users as you want. Also, I was able to add one security group to another. Please see my updates answer with Screens.

Comment: @DvG my needs are i have a company that many sub branch,hence am creating groups for the sub branch and one group to add all the sub-branch. I have been trying with the different group type and found only mail-enabled security group and distribution group can be used to send mail in Microsoft Flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with sending the emails to a group rather you should make sure that **emails are enabled for that group.**
There could be 2 cases:

1. you are sending emails to Sharepoint Group which has members as individual people. *(Sending emails works perfectly since it treats every user as one object and people are email-enabled by default)*
2. You are sending the emails directly to an O365 security group OR a SharePoint group that has members as an O365 security group. *(You need to be sure that it is email-enabled, additionally)*

Creating a mail-enabled security group using PowerShell

> new-distributiongroup -name "[Group's Name]" -alias "[Group's Alias]"
>   -type "security" -primarysmtpaddress "[your_address@your_domain]"

Refer : [MSDN 1](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb123521(v=exchg.150).aspx) and [MSDN 2](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-edit-or-delete-a-security-group-in-the-Office-365-admin-center-55c96b32-e086-4c9e-948b-a018b44510cb)

**Edit 1**:
Additionally, you can create an O365 group of Type - Distribution List. It has its own mail-box. You can put 2 or more mail-enabled sec groups in it.

*Note:* I am able to add the one email-enabled-sec-group to another email-enabled-sec-group. Refer SS:

[image]

Adding Test2mail-enabled-sec to test1-mail-enabled-sec group:

[image]

Comment: The problem here with mail-enabled security group is,i can't add another group to it. What i did is create a security group which allow me to add sub group to it which is i used to give permission and i created a separate mail enabled  security group to send alerts

Comment: You can add, mail-enabled security group to another one. Refer SS and my updated answer. Let me know if you have any query

Comment: quick question can we share a site and assign permission to a distribution list?

Comment: @Keshav, You cannot assign/share permission to a distribution list from your SharePoint site. Additionally, Based on your comment about problem statement you have, the mail-enable-security group will work for you like a charm. Since you can put one group to another mail-enabled-sec-grp and do nesting of groups

Comment: @Keshav.. Did this solved your problem?

Comment: we can't add subgroup to mail enable security group

Comment: What Sub Group are you referring to? Is it SP group or something else. I am able to add test1-mail-enabled-sec-group to test2mail-enabled-sec-group.

Answer (score 1):

1. Navigate to site settings -> People and groups
2. Click Groups in the left nav bar
3. Create a new group
4. Now in the email when you select the cc/To section you will see the group name there. Select that.

Make sure you the "on create" and/or "on edit" are checked

Comment: doesn't work with Microsoft Flow

Comment: You should use SharePoint designer. You can create a email workflow - on create and on edit

Comment: are you sure you can send email to GROUP if i use SharePoint designer ? if yes what type of group should i use?

Comment: I have done this many times. Its done in SharePoint O365. There are no groups types. Create your own custom group. Add members to it. It's pretty easy.

Comment: does it work if the group contain sub-group ?

Comment: You can't have sub-groups, but you can send the same mail to multiple groups.
To create a group :
 https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-create-a-group-and-add-a-user-in-sharepoint-online/

Email WF: 
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138529/send-email-using-sharepoint-designer-to-the-users-in-person-and-group-field?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

Use Sharepoint designer 2013 workflow.

Please Reffer below link to get more clarification..

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/send-e-mail-in-a-workflow-11d5f9dd-955f-412c-b70f-cde4214204f4

Comment: Hi Sibin, I think Keshav already knows how to send email alerts as he tried it by creating SP List alerts as well as used the MS Flows also. So the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @DvG please see updated question